Chrome Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie" for flutter web app
I am building a web app with a Flutter front-end and a PHP back-end. Currently implementing login session management. I have set up my session management logic on my PHP backend and tested it with Postman. Works perfectly fine. The main logic here is that I generate a token and then store it on the client's side as a cookie and on my database. If the cookie exists on the client's side and the token matches the one on the database, that user will automatically be logged in. I'm confident that the server-side logic works fine. But on the front-end, chrome keeps returning: Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie"
This is my flutter code:
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as HTTP;
import 'package:cookie_jar/cookie_jar.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class AuthRemoteRepository {

final http.Client client = http.Client();
final CookieJar cookieJar = CookieJar();
final String baseUrl = 'http://192.168.0.111/indiewave/api';

Future<void> signup({
  required String mail,
  required String name,
  required String password,
}) async {
  try {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('http://192.168.0.111/indiewave/api/Signup'),
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: jsonEncode({"email": mail, "name": name, "password": password}),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('Signup successful: ${response.body}');
    } else {
      print('Signup failed: ${response.statusCode} - ${response.body}');
    }
  } catch (e, stackTrace) {
    print('Error during signup: $e');
    print('Stack trace: $stackTrace');
  }
}

  Future<void> login({
    required String mail,
    required String password,
    required bool keepLoggedIn,
  }) async {
    try {
      final uri = Uri.parse('http://192.168.0.111/indiewave/api/Login');
      final response = await http.post(
        uri,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: jsonEncode({"email": mail, "password": password, "keepLoggedIn": 
        keepLoggedIn}),
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print('Login successful: ${response.body}');
        final cookies = response.headers['set-cookie'];
        if (cookies != null) {
          await cookieJar.saveFromResponse(uri, [Cookie.fromSetCookieValue(cookies)]);
        }
      } else {
        print('Login failed: ${response.statusCode} - ${response.body}');
      }
   } catch (e, stackTrace) {
      print('Error during Login: $e');
      print('Stack trace: $stackTrace');
  }
}

  Future<bool> autologin() async {
    try {
      final uri = Uri.parse('http://192.168.0.111/indiewave/api/Login');
      final cookies = await cookieJar.loadForRequest(uri);
      final cookieHeader = cookies.map((cookie) => 
'${cookie.name}=${cookie.value}').join('; ');
  
      final response = await http.post(
          uri,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Cookie': cookieHeader,
      },
          body: jsonEncode({"email": "dummy@example.com", "password": "dummypass", 
"keepLoggedIn": false}),
        );
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          return true;
        }
        else  {
          return false;
        }
    } catch(e) {
        print('Error during auto-login: $e');
        return false;
    }
  }

}
I think the main issue is in this part:
final response = await http.post(
      uri,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Cookie': cookieHeader,
        },
      body: jsonEncode({"email": "dummy@example.com", "password": "dummypass", "keepLoggedIn": false}),
    );

maybe this is not allowed. But I need to send cookies with my requests somehow
